# How ssh clients distinguish colors of text

Tags: java, ssh

I'm trying to write a simple ssh client using java library 'sshj'.

```
try {
    session = ssh.startSession();
    try {
        final Command cmd = session.exec("ls");
        System.out.println(IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString());
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
} finally {
    ssh.disconnect();
}
```

But, my problem is that I can't figure out how ssh clients (like putty or iterms) distinguish colors of text (for example, colors in vi or colors for the result of command 'ls').

I searched Google a little bit with queries like 'ssh protocol text color' or something, but I couldn't find a satisfying result.

And I find out some ssh java libraries like jsch, sshj and sshtools, and
I'm using sshj because it's short codes. But if you have any comments about these libraries, feel free to share it to me :)

Comment: They don't. They interpret and display the [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and represent a software terminal for you. Think [vt-100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100).

Comment: if you jsch and open a shell channel, then you can also have this annoying feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh simply forwards (and encrypts/decrypts) bytes between the server and the client. In most cases the server is running a unix shell and "the bytes" are simply stdin/stdout/stderr from that shell.

If you run vim in that shell, then the bytes are produced by vim. To do the special stuff like colors (syntax highlighting), positioning of the cursor and so on, vim will send escape sequences, which are series of bytes starting with an "ESCAPE" byte (hex 27).

Escape sequences stem from the days of "green terminals" and are interpreted as "instructions" by the physical terminal, or the terminal emulator e.g. putty.

Vim and other complex terminal programs will look for the $TERM environment variable to determine what terminal you are using client-side. Depending on that value, the escape sequences (think terminal-dependent instructions) will be different.

You can find many lists of terminal escape sequences on the internet, e.g. for ansi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code